# How to read a long text in a cell that's a result of a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a text cell that needs to in the "Clipping" wrap mode, cutting most of it away from view. Or is at the end of the range. Or is too long to be displayed. Normally, I would read the cell by selecting it and reading it in the formula bar.

But if the cell is a result of a formula (such as `=join(", ", A1:A300)` which results in a long text) the formula bar only displays the formula, not the resulting text.

Is there some sort of keyboard shortcut or setting that helps with this?

Answer (score 0):

Fast way is to copy and paste values in another cell